# Как получить адрес верзушки стэка через getter- метод аргумента конструктора копирования?

Tags: c++

```
    #pragma once
    #ifndef _Steak_H_

    #include"Node.h"
    #include<cstdlib>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<iomanip>

    using namespace std;

    #define _Steak_H_

    class Stack
    {
        Node *hight_stack_ptr;// Верхушка стэка

    public:

        Stack(const Stack &obg);//Конструктор копирования

        Node *get_hight_steak_ptr();
    }

----------------

//cpp file
#include "Stack.h"

Stack::Stack()
{
    hight_stack_ptr = nullptr;
}

Stack::Stack(const Stack &obg)
{
    hight_stack_ptr = nullptr;

    Node ptr = obg.get_hight_steak_ptr();//Почему нельзя вызвать метод get???

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, вызвать его нельзя, потому что метод объявлен как неконстантный, так что для константного `obj` его не вызвать...

Объявите его как

```
Node *get_hight_steak_ptr() const;
```

Только вот что вы хотите получить - в смысле вашего

> Как получить адрес верзушки стэка

Почему вы считаете, что этот метод дает вам "верхушку стека"?... что-то, по-моему, у вас не так в самом заголовке вопроса...